# CSS Positioning of an existing item

Tags: css

I'm trying to position the bird on this site: http://dane.helpful.ninja/fds/ inside the grey box. It should be positioned mid height.

I dont know why but it won't let me do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Link not working. :(

Comment: Still not working. Might be ISP issue.! can you add screenshot for the same.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `#birdy` element has `position: absolute`, it is placed with respect to the whole document. You need to set a relative parent container.

```
.jumbotron {
  position: relative; /* Add */
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Middle absolute positioning]

Comment: Not a problem :) Please try to add some related code to the question now/next time.